# How to get route prefix name from url in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How can I get the route prefix name dynamically in Laravel 5.3?

For example, here's the URL:

> http://localhost/lara/public/admin/login

And here's the routes file. The route group prefix is `admin`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches "/admin/users"
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Laravel's routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing)? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to get group name dynamically. Actually it may be different name like admin, user etc

Comment: Once again, Atul, have you looked at [Laravel's routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing)? It shows how to capture parts of your URL. And if you are really referring to Laravel's route groups, they're in there too.

Comment: Thanks for adding some code. Now _where_ are you trying to get the route prefix name? In a controller? In a template? How could it be dynamically defined?

Comment: Actually I need on both places. I tried on controller $request->route()->getPrefix() and It gives me "/{admin}"

Comment: …isn't that what you want? Why doesn't that result suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're asking, but I guess you want to be able to configure your route group prefix dynamically. For example, being able to dynamically change administration area's URI prefix.

Let's add a corresponding config directive to the `config/app.php` file:

```
return [
    // ...

    'admin_url' => 'backoffice',
];
```

Then in your route file:

```
// Fetch the prefix from the config file, fallback to "admin" if not available
Route::group(['prefix' => config('app.admin_url', 'admin')], function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Then in the controllers, you can access the defined route prefix either with the same call to `config()` helper, or `$request->route()->getPrefix()`.

If there's no `$request` instance in the context, you can get the prefix with `$this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix()` in any controller.